# Ngrx effects: filtering actions based on their common property

Tags: typescript, ngrx, typescript-typings, ngrx-effects

I have a number of ngrx actions, which have a common property `choice`:

```
export const actionA = createAction('a', props<{oneProperty: number, choice: boolean}>());
export const actionB = createAction('b', props<{anotherProperty: string, choice: boolean}>());
export const actionC = createAction('c', props<{choice: boolean}>());
```

I would like to refer to this property in my component, as:

```
constructor(private actions$: Actions) {
  actions$.pipe(filter(action => action.choice)).subscribe(...
}
```

However, doing so naively leads to a type error, as `actions$` is an `Observable<Action>`, and a generic `Action` doesn't know about `choice`. If there was just one-two actions like this, I could use [ofType](https://ngrx.io/api/effects/ofType) to narrow the type, as:

```
actions$.pipe(ofType('a', 'b'), filter(action => (<choice: boolean>action).choice))
```

as here, 'action' will be of type `ActionA|ActionB`. I have many such actions however and cannot hardcode them here. I tried passing a list of actions like this:

```
const actionList = ['a', 'b'];
actions$.pipe(ofType(...actionList), filter(action => (<choice: boolean>action).choice))
```

but `ofType(...allowedTypes)` doesn't allow inference. The docs also say:
`Type narrowing automatically works, as long as your actions object starts with a Actions<SomeUnionOfActions> instead of generic Actions.` I tried to make `Actions` a union with:

```
constructor(private actions$: Actions<typeof actionA>)
```

but this didn't type. I also tried `Actions<{choice: boolean}>`, but this didn't type either.
How can I use a common property of all of my actions in the `Actions` effect without hardcoding all of their names there?

Comment: You could use `ofType(actionA, actionB, actionC...)`, instead of typing their names manually.

Comment: That's arguably not much different from putting all names down: ideally, I wouldn't have to define all of them anywhere, but if I have to, it would be much better to do it closer to where the actions are defined and not where they are used.

Comment: @sygi the problem when you call `ofType` passing plain strings, as you're doing is that TS can't help you of course because it's a simple string. On other hand, when you provide an `ActionCreator`, it can surely infer the type of `<props>` and everything should work as you may expect.